# Javascript access variables through parameter

Tags: javascript, function

Below code, I need to access variable a inside call function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var a=10;
call("a");
function call(x) {
//alert 10 using x
}
});
```

Please dont change the code, just write the correct alert statement

Comment: Try `alert(window[x]);`. I tested it in Chrome and works, idk about the other browser, but in FF will work too.

Comment: does not work, tried it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var a=10;
  call(a);
  function call(x) {
   alert(x);
  }
});
```

In your code you are passing the variable as a string. so it won't do the things as are expecting. You may use `eval()` for this purpose, that is reading a value from the string formatted variable name. But it is not a recommended one since it is modifying the scope at runtime.

Comment: You changed the code, i assume.

Comment: @Romeo Nope i didn't change anything. Just formatted the code for a better view and just added my thoughts on it.

Comment: He has `call("a");`, you put `call(a);`. Anyway, i didn't downvote you.

Comment: you have changed the code! a is not passed as a var in my code, a as a string is passed. Have a look!